# Publishing iOS App on TestFlight in a team

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I want to publish app on TestFlight for my client. He added me on team on app store connect as Admin, but in Xcode I can't see that team and I can't archive my app because of that. Does anybody maybe know how I can fix this?

I tried to log out and log in, restart my mac and delete cache memory from Xcode but it didn't help.

Comment: have you downloaded the new provisioning profiles and distribution certificates ?

Comment: for that, you have to add your client account in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are logged in to the account you were added with in Xcode.  To do that, go to the Xcode Menu > Settings > Accounts.  If the account isn't in the area on the left use the + button in the lower left to add it.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without login in on the account I was added?